# How do I get the rest of the code to print?

Tags: python

My code is only printing up to the first set of else if statements how do I get it for my code to print the next set of else if.

```
player=input("Player name:")
hits=int(input("Hits:"))
ab=int(input("At Bats:"))
walks=int(input("Walks:"))
hbp=int(input("Hit By Pitch:"))
tb=int(input("Total Bases:"))

ba=hits/ab
obp=(hits+walks+hbp)/(ab+walks+hbp)
slg= tb/ab
iso= slg - ba
ops= obp + slg


print(player,"hit","{:.3f}".format(ba))
print(player,"On-base Percentage was","{:.3f}".format(obp))
print(player,"slugged","{:.3f}".format(slg))
print(player,"Had an isolated power of","{:.3f}".format(iso))
print(player,"Had on-base plus slugging od","{:.3f}".format(ops))

if ba >= .300:
    print(player,"batting average is elite")
elif .299 >= ba >= .280:
    print(player,"batting average is great")
elif .279 >= ba >= .260:
    print(player,"batting average is above average")
elif .259 >= ba >= .250:
    print(player,"batting average is average")
elif ba <= .249:
    print(player,"batting average is below average")
    
if obp >= .390:
    print(player,"On base percentage is elite")
elif .389 >= obp >= .370:
    print(player,"On base percentage is great")
elif .269 >= obp >= .340:
    print(player,"On base percentage is above average")
elif .339 >= obp >= .320:
    print(player,"On base percentage is above average")
elif obp <= .319:
    print(player,"On base percentage is below average")
```

This what happens when is run it

```
#input:
#Player name: jose
#Hits: 167
#At Bats:601
#Walks:66
#Hit By Pitch:4
#Total Bases:294

#output:
 #jose hit 0.278
 #jose On-base Percentage was 0.353
 #jose slugged 0.489
 #jose Had an isolated power of 0.211
 #jose Had on-base plus slugging od 0.842
 #jose batting average is above average
```

I want the program to print the next statement "player on-base percentage is xxx"

> > > 

Comment: Typo: `elif .269 >= obp >= .340:` I think you want `.369`

Comment: What do you expect when the player's OBP is 0.3895?

Comment: The comparisons can just be: `if obp >= .390: ... elif obp >= .370: ... elif obp >= .340: ... elif obp >= .320: ... else ... `

Comment: None of the conditions match the obp of 0.353 in your example. Which is why nothing is printed

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo at `elif .269 >= obp >= .340:`, you probably meant to type `.369`, but that is not the main issue.

You are missing some values. You have

```
if obp >= .390:
    ...
elif .389 >= obp >= .370:
```

What happens if the value is `.3895`, for example? That's less than `.390` but more than `.389` so it doesn't meet any condition. You may not be seeing values like this because you are hiding them with the string format `{:.3f}`.

The fix is:

```
if obp >= .390:
    print(player,"On base percentage is elite")
elif obp >= .370:
    print(player,"On base percentage is great")
elif obp >= .340:
    print(player,"On base percentage is above average")
elif obp >= .320:
    print(player,"On base percentage is average")
else
    print(player,"On base percentage is below average")
```

This works because once a `true` condition is found and the body of that case is executed, all others after it will be ignored - even though they are also `true`.